# Session is not getting destroyed MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-timeout

I am trying to check if session is still alive in every 5 seconds using this jquery function

```
setTimeout(IsSessionAlive, 5000);

 function IsSessionAlive()
 {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("IsSessionAlive", "Account")', function (isAlive) {
       if (!isAlive)
         alert(isAlive);
         setTimeout(IsSessionAlive, 5000);
     });
 }
```

And this is how I am trying to fetch session state from server

```
public JsonResult IsSessionAlive()
{
   var isA = Request.IsAuthenticated;
   return Json(Session["LoggedIn"] != null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

just to test the code I am doing this on LogOn

```
Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
Session.Timeout = 1;
```

And I am expecting that it should destroy the session after 1 minute of inactivity and when my jquery will check the session it will find it null and will show user the popup that you have to enter the password again.
But I never find the session null!!
Any Idea?

Comment: Your session will expire after 1 minute of inactivity. But since your cause activity every 5 seconds, this is never going to happen.

Comment: Ohh! It will be considered as user activity???

Comment: Yes, for the web server it's a request like any other.

Comment: Oh ok! So is there any other way to achieve this, there are jquery plugins, but they all seem to have some bugs or limitations. So I thought checking session will be the safest.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect Idle Timeout using [jQuery idleTimer plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) & show the popup once the timeout occurs.

**Sample Code:**

```
// idleTimer() takes an optional argument that defines the idle timeout
// timeout is in milliseconds; defaults to 30000
$.idleTimer(10000);


$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user goes idle
});


$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function(){
 // function you want to fire when the user becomes active again
});

// pass the string 'destroy' to stop the timer
$.idleTimer('destroy');
```

Comment: That is just great! But is there any reason of my problem?